# CSS: Box Shadow Effect on Scalene Triangle PseudoElement

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a box shadow around a scalene triangle that exists as a pseudo element, as shown below. I have tried many ways but cannot seem to get an even shadow below my image.

I have tried putting a second scalene triangle pseudo element with slightly larger dimensions that is grey but since there is no gradient or shadow effect, it is not what I am looking for.

Does anyone have any solutions?

Would really appreciate some ideas; perhaps there is a way to get a border gradient effect on a second pseudo element and underlay it?

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 40px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
}

.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 80px solid transparent;
  border-top: 30px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div style='width: 300px;height:300px;background: white;'>
  <div class='box'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#drop-shadow()_2)!

```
filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
```

Maps the shadow around the visible parts of the element, instead of its box.

Note that this property is significantly different from and incompatible with Microsoft's older "filter" property.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look on this fiddle I have made: https://jsfiddle.net/1fwrn3wh/1/.

The steps you need to do:

1. Add a :before pseudo element which the same size of :after element
2. Slightly move :before element downward
3. Add the filter with blur aspect

Then it will alike the shadow ;)

For your quick editing, you can add this CSS into your file:

```
.box:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 105%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 80px solid transparent;
  border-top: 30px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  filter: blur(2px);
}
```

And then change the box-shadow of the original box:

```
box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
```

Cheer ;)